# Milnor and Moore paper "On the structure of Hopf algebra" proposition 1.7 , filtration and grading

Tags: hopf-algebras, filters

In the Milnor and Moore paper, "[On the structure of Hopf algebras](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970615)" proposition 1.7 said the following:

> 1. $A$ a connected $K$-algebra.
> 2. $N$ a left $A$ module that is connected as a $K$-graded module i.e. there is an isomorphism $\eta_N:K\to N_0$ which results in an
>    augmentation $\varepsilon_N:N\to K$.
> 3. $C=K\otimes_A N$, here $K$ is considered as $A$-rightmodule by the action $K\otimes A \xrightarrow{\cong} A \xrightarrow{\varepsilon_A} K$.
> 4. $\Delta :N \to N\otimes C$ a morphism of left $A$ modules.
> 5. $\pi:N\to C$ the canonical epimorphism. Let $f:C\to N$ such that $\pi f = \operatorname{id}_C$. In this paper they used $C$ the object letter to indicate
>    the identity morphism.
> 6. $(\varepsilon_N\otimes C)\circ \Delta =\pi$.
> 7. $(N\otimes \varepsilon_C)\circ \Delta = N$.
> 8. $A\otimes C \xrightarrow{i\otimes C} N\otimes C $ is a monomorphism.
>
> If $\tilde{f}$ is the composition $$A\otimes C
>  \xrightarrow{A\otimes f} A \otimes N \xrightarrow{\varphi_N} N$$ then $\tilde f$ is an isomorphism.

The map $i$ is defined as the composition
$$A\xrightarrow{\cong} A\otimes K \xrightarrow{A\otimes \eta_N} A\otimes N \xrightarrow{\varphi_N} N$$
and $\varphi_N$ is the left action of $A$ on $N$.

**My first question:** in the process to show that $\tilde{f}$ is a
monomorphism, they showed $\Delta \tilde{f}$ is a monomorphism.

They define a filtration on $$F_p(A\otimes C) = \sum_{q\leq p} A\otimes C_q \text{ and } F_p(N\otimes C) = \sum_{q\leq p} N\otimes C_q$$
Then they said: "let $E^0 (A\otimes C)$ be the associated bigraded module."
Is this the grading associated with the filtration i.e. $\operatorname{gr}_p(A\otimes C) = F_p/F_{p-1}$? Or it is just the grading on $A$ and $C$ as $K$-modules? I guess it is the second since they said $E^0_{p,q} (A\otimes C) = A_p \otimes C_q$.

After that they said we identify $E^0(A\otimes C)$ with $A\otimes C$. Then why did they introduce the $E^0$?

**Second question:** How come the two following morphisms are the same:
$$A\otimes C \xrightarrow{A\otimes f} A\otimes N \xrightarrow{\varphi_N} N\to_{\Delta} N\otimes C$$
and $i\otimes C$ which is
$$A\otimes C \xrightarrow{\cong\otimes C } A\otimes K\otimes C  \xrightarrow{A\otimes \eta_N\otimes C } A\otimes N \otimes C \xrightarrow{\varphi_N} N\otimes C. $$

Comment: The notation $E^0_{p,q)$ suggests (to me) that they plan to use it as page 0 of a spectral sequence.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But for the this proposition there is not significant right?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1162898), I think @AndreasBlass was answering your question "why did they introduce the $E^0$ [if they are just going to identify it with $A \otimes C$."  I think shortened links are usually inappropriate on MO, since you can't easily see in advance where they go, so I replaced it with a DOI link.  The original link is still commented out in the source, if you believe it belongs. MathJax note: the `> Blockquote` line is not needed; just `>` blockquotes. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice thanks for the edits, I figured out that it is related to spectral sequence but I did see where to apply in this maybe later on in the paper. Am still at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $E^0(A\otimes C)$ can be identified with $A\otimes C$ as objects, this is not compatible with morphisms.  If $g\colon A\otimes C\to A\otimes C$ is a map of graded groups, then the map $g\colon A_i\otimes C_j\to(A\otimes C)_{i+j}$ can be expressed as a sum of morphisms $g_k\colon A_i\otimes C_j\to A_{i+k}\otimes C_{i-k}$.  If $g$ preserves the filtration then $g_k=0$ for all $k<0$, and $E^0(g)=g_0$, whereas $g=\sum_{k\geq 0}g_k$.

In the case of interest, we have $g=\Delta\circ\widetilde{f}$.  For $a\in A_i$ and $c\in C_j$ we have $g(a\otimes c)=\Delta(a\,f(c))$, but $\Delta$ is a map of $A$-modules by condition 4, so $g(a)=a\,\Delta(f(c))$.  Here $\Delta(f(c))$ can be written as $\sum_{k=0}^jx_k$ with $x_k\in N_k\otimes C_{j-k}$ so $g_k(a\otimes c)=ax_k$ and $E^0(g)(a\otimes c)=g_0(a\otimes c)=ax_0$.  On the other hand, $\epsilon$ is zero on $N_k$ for $k>0$ and $N_0=K$ so $x_0$ is essentially the same as $(\epsilon\otimes 1)(\Delta(f(c)))$, which is $\pi(f(c))=c$ by condition 6.  Here we have implicitly identified $C$ with $K\otimes C\leq A\otimes C$; if we unwrap that we get $x_0=1\otimes c$ and $ax_0=a\otimes c$ in $A\otimes C$.  This means that $E^0(\Delta\circ\widetilde{f})$ is the identity.

Comment: What does it means to preserve filteration? does it $g(F_p) = F_p$ or it is subset of $F_p$?, and why if it preserve filteration then it is $E^0$ is zero for non-zero filters.

Comment: I have a question, $g:A\otimes C\to A\otimes C$, I learned that $g_n:(A\otimes C)_n \to (A\otimes C)_n$ where $(A\otimes C)_n = \bigoplus_{i+j} A_i\otimes C_j$ but it seems you picked one. Can you provide me with a good book about this topic thanks!